# copying text in tableview (swift)

Tags: ios, tableview

I have a tableview controller, and the text in the cells are in the "basic" style.  I just typed in the text I wanted with the labels it gave me with the basic styles... How can i let the user now, be able to hold down on the text and be able to copy the text to the clipboard?

I was able to find answers to this problem for objective-c, but not for swift.  I thought it was probably in the inspector, the answer for my problem. But I can't find anything in the inspector that will allow me to do that, unless i just skipped it without noticing it.

I have tested on a real device and simulator

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed a few English issues with your post.  Please provide an example of you code.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to copy data from label is using default methods of UITableView:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView performAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withSender:(id)sender;
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView canPerformAction:(SEL)action forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath withSender:(id)sender;
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView shouldShowMenuForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;
```

and their equivalents in swift:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canPerformAction action: 
Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if (action.description == "copy:") {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performAction action: Selector, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, withSender sender: Any?) {
    if (action.description == "copy:") {
        //...
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldShowMenuForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```